# how to create single router script in react application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, router

I want to try making a script to manage my page in application like react-router,vue-router.
The script has a list which to configure pages list. The pages list include name,component path,params of pages.

The problem is how to import the page component with configured page list.
I try to use "import xx from path" but node tell me import only will be use top level.
And then i use the "import(path)",it will load a object but not execute.
I try to use "require",and it will load a module.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App'; //it works

function Login(){
   return 'login';
}

function Home(){
   return 'home';
}

const Routers = [
    { path : '/' , component : <Home/> },
    { path : 'index' , component : <Home/> },
    { path : 'home' , component : <Home/> },
    { path : 'login' , component : <Login/> },
    { path : 'app' , component : <App /> },
    // { path : 'app' , component : import from './App' }, //it don't work
    // { path : 'app' , component : import('./App') }, //it don't work
    // { path : 'app' , component : require('./App') },//it don't work
]
const root = document.getElementById('root');
ReactDOM.render(Routers[0].component, root)

const hash2component = (url)=>{
    let path = url.split("#")[1] || '/';
    const router = Routers.filter((e)=>{
        return e.path == path
    })
    const component = router?.length?router[0].component:'404';
    return component;
}

window.onhashchange = (e)=>{
    console.log(hash2component(e.newURL))
    ReactDOM.render(hash2component(e.newURL), root)
}
```

How can i import the component app in the Routers list?

Comment: `import xx from path` should work. Can you show in the sample code how you did this, and the exact error that you get?

Comment: @RegisterSole I mean use "import xx from path" in the router list directly and i don't works.

Comment: @taolu — Well, don't do that. Import it at the top, then use the variable it is assigned to when you want to use it.

Comment: @Quentin When i use import(path) directly,it return promise resolved.So i can't use the function.

Comment: Why on earth is your *component* being generated from a promise? Sounds like any data it needs should either be passed in through a prop or fetched with a useEffect

Comment: @Quentin I konw little about the "import()".But it return promise object surely.This is the code in below commit.

Comment: It doesn't return a promise when you use it at [the top of the function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) in the normal way (i.e. in the way you import `React`).  You only get a promise when you use a [dynamic import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#dynamic_imports).

Comment: @Quentin Thank you for your suggests about "dynamic import".It work well when i use import('xxx') .But when the parameter of import is a string,it doesn't work.It shows "Error: Cannot find module 'xxx'";The path of both is the same.

Comment: The path isn't the same, because one is processed by your transpiler and uses node module resolution and the other is processed by the browser and uses URLs. I don't recommend dynamic module imports for you. I recommend importing the module at the top.

Comment: Thanks for your solutions.The code for example"async ()=>await import('./Index.js')".Is it dynamic import mode after compiled with webpack?

Answer (score 0):

I find a way to import react component.
The import(path) returns a module.I can get the react component by Using the method of module.

index.js

```
import router from './common/router';
const root = document.getElementById('root');
router.init(root);
```

Router.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Home from '../components/Home';

const Routers = [
    { path : '' , component : <Home/> },
    { path : '/' , component : <Home/> },
    { path : 'index' , component : <Home/> },
    { path : 'home' , component : <Home/> },
    { path : 'login' , component : require('../components/Login.js') },//other component
    { path : 'app' , component :  require('../App.js') },//other component
]

var root;

const init =  (elemnt)=>{
    root = elemnt;
}

const hash2component =  (url)=>{
    let path = url.split("#")[1] || '/';
    return  path2component(path);
}

const path2component =  (path)=>{
    const router = Routers.filter((e)=>{
        return e.path == path
    })
    let component = router?.length?router[0].component:null;
    if(typeof (component)=='object'){
        // component =  component();
        component = component.default?component.default():component;
    }
    return component || '404';
}

window.onhashchange = (e)=>{
    ReactDOM.render(hash2component(e.newURL), root)
}

window.onload = ()=>{
    ReactDOM.render(hash2component(window.location.href), root)
}

const pagestack = [];

const getHome = ()=>{
    return hash2component('/');
}

const push = (path)=>{
    return path2component(path);
}

const forEach = ()=>{
    return [];
}

export default {
    init,
    pagestack,
    getHome,
    // push,
    // forEach,
}
```